# innodb data file of several GB size

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have a MySQL database (version 5.6.21-log) which InnoDB data file has grown to several GB to the point of totally filling the disk space.

How can I debug this issue? Is it normal that this file grows to that size?

The file is the one configured by:

```
innodb-data-file-path=system.tbs:10M:autoextend
```

Comment: Why do you think it's an issue? - tables grow as you populate them and you have to have a strategy in place for dealing with that - either bigger disks or archive delete.

Comment: It is far more likely that your application which uses the said innodb database needs debugging, not MySQL if the database size is way above your expectations. There are ways to shrink innodb files, but such question has nothing to do with sw development, so is not topic on here.

Comment: where can I as such a question then?

It is an issue because my Database is in its specific folder, with all the tables as files (fwd and idb), and it takes 25GB. This file... I don't know what does it contain...

Comment: You can arrange for each table to have its own set of files, but unfortunately even if you do that you can't shrink the original file without a complete backup/reinstall/reload cycle. Off topic. @P.Salmon It's an issue because he has filled up his disk space. This is clearly stated in the question.

Comment: There is dba.stackexchange.com sister site of SO, which is specifically for database administration questions. SO is for software development.

Comment: @user207421 P.Salmon was right to ask the question because the OP immediately assumed that the database file size was incorrect. However, it is possible that there is a valid reason why the db size grew so much and the OP need to get some more hard disks.

Comment: @Shadow *Or* separate the table files as I said and re-install.